# Can i finetune deeplab to a custom dataset in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, pre-trained-model, semantic-segmentation

I would like to customize deeplab for image segmentation using my own dataset ? Is this achievable by retraining ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you should follow one of [these tutorials](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab#tables-of-contents), depending on the dataset format you have, where you get how to convert datasets to TFrecord format, and train model.

If you use Pascal voc 2012 format, there is a complete [example here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/05ccaf88f7bd617a614f96a2414602f571cc2768/research/deeplab/local_test.sh), including all the steps for training, evaluation, visualize results, and export model.

Answer (score 10):

On [Deeplab official tutorial page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/pascal.md), the training commands looks like this:

```
python deeplab/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --training_number_of_steps=30000 \
    --train_split="train" \
    --model_variant="xception_65" \
    --atrous_rates=6 \
    --atrous_rates=12 \
    --atrous_rates=18 \
    --output_stride=16 \
    --decoder_output_stride=4 \
    --train_crop_size=513 \
    --train_crop_size=513 \
    --train_batch_size=1 \
    --dataset="pascal_voc_seg" \
    --tf_initial_checkpoint=${PATH_TO_INITIAL_CHECKPOINT} \
    --train_logdir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_dir=${PATH_TO_DATASET}
```

By changing `dataset_dir` and `dataset` and a few lines in [`segmentation_dataset.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/segmentation_dataset.py), you can train on your own dataset.

- `dataset_dir`: path points to your **tfrecord folder**.

  Inside  this folder, you should have `train-%05d-of-%05d.tfrecord` and `val-%05d-of-%05d.tfrecord` created by [build_voc2012_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/build_voc2012_data.py) or other scripts in [datasets](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab/datasets).

  Accordingly, if you want to use `train.tfrecord` for training, set `train_split` to `train`; if you want to evaluate on your evaluation data, set `train_split` to `val`.
- `dataset`: any self defined name, say "donkey_monkey"
- Inside [`segmentation_dataset.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/segmentation_dataset.py)

  create `DatasetDescriptor` for your own dataset:

  ```
  _DONKEY_MONKEY_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
  splits_to_sizes={
      'train': 1464,  # number of training examples in train data
      'trainval': 2913,  # number of examples for train+eval
      'val': 1449,  # number of eval examples 
      },
      num_classes=21, # note: should be number of class + background
      ignore_label=255,  # label pixels to ignore
  )
  ```

  change below code (line 112)

  ```
  _DATASETS_INFORMATION = {
      'cityscapes': _CITYSCAPES_INFORMATION,
      'pascal_voc_seg': _PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION,
      'ade20k': _ADE20K_INFORMATION,
      'donkey_monkey': _DONKEY_MONKEY_INFORMATION, # newly added
   }
  ```